# Excel VSTO Addin EnableEvents

Tags: excel

I am migrating an Excel addin from VBA to VSTO.  My addin is triggered by a worksheet changeevent but writes its answer to the worksheet.  So I have to set EnableEvents = False at the start and True when it has finished, otherwise I get an endless loop.
When I use the same code in my VSTO addin, I get an "Exception User Unhandled" message.  Can anybody point me to material which shows how to turn EnableEvents on and off in VSTO addin.  I've been searching the internet for several days but can find nothing.
[image]

I expected the "myApp.EnableEvents = False" statement to turn off the SheetChange event but it doesn't.